# ListView Android does not allow selector to work nor does it allows selections

Tags: android, listview, highlight, simplecursoradapter, focusable

Okay I know this may sound like any other issues regarding the ListView and ListActivity issues but this is not, I am going to go crazy as I have in the past week gone on and on searching all post to find any solution to this that may help me. Already tried [ListView item background via custom selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562051/listview-item-background-via-custom-selector) and [GetView Vs. BindView in a custom CursorAdapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535074/getview-vs-bindview-in-a-custom-cursoradapter) every other possible blogs sites...

Okay the issue, My listView for one 1 will not allows selection/fire events and 2. will not change the row highlight when an item is clicked. I have a standard `TestActivity` extending `ListActivity` and I have implemented a Custom `TestCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter`

Now in XML side of things I have on `test_list_view.xml` and second one `row_view.xml` Now I followed the above mentions answers and implement `selector` as `row_selector.xml`. But the issue is for one the rows does not accept any click or focus events. I implemented a basic toast to indicate if there is anything happening

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v , int postion, long idontnow){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello World",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
}
```

### part of test_list_view.xml

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" 
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:focusable="true" 
    android:listSelector="@color/row_selector" 
    android:background="@color/Transparent"/>
```

### part of selector.xml (basically copied and pasted from one of the above mentioned links)

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" 
        android:drawable="@color/Transparent" />
    <item 
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@color/green" />
    <item 
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_enabled="false"      
        android:drawable="@color/green" />
    <item 
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@color/blue" />
    <item 
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@color/blue" />
    <item 
        android:state_focused="true" 
        android:drawable="@color/green" />
    <item 
        android:state_selected="true" 
        android:drawable="@color/blue" />
    <item 
        android:drawable="@color/Transparent" />
</selector>
```

I followed all options that I am aware of and still nothing. **The only major difference is guys I am not using `getView` instead I am using `bindView`.**

Any help guys will be highly appreciated.

thanks in advance.

Sanj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you remove the `android:focusable="true"` from the `ListView`.

Additionally, you can use the `selector` as the background color of the items that are displayed in the `ListView`. Also be sure that those elements are not calling `onClick` or `onTouch` or something like that, and let the `ListView` handle the click events.

I hope this helps

**EDIT:**

for your problem with selecting the item use

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            yourMethod();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Raukodraug, it kind of works since I applied the selector to every item the back color does show however it still does not select the row, i.e. doesn't fire the event

Comment: Im glad it helped you, for your other problem, Ive edited the answer

Comment: i will give it a world in next 5 hours.

Comment: It kind of works followed this items. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367936/listview-onitemclicklistener-not-responding

Answer (score 1):

following raukodraug's suggestion and post 
[ListView OnItemClickListener Not Responding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367936/listview-onitemclicklistener-not-responding)

Another fact as mentioned use `bindView` method, I used

```
view.setClickable(true);
view.setFocusable(true);
```

the item click kind of works, only if you click on the region marked highlighted in Yellow and the `ImageView`. I should be able to figure this out thanks,

[image]

**Edited**

Oh *%#$ Solved it, Needed to set the RelativeLayouts `Add State from Children = true;`