# Cursor not binding text correctly with custom adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-cursoradapter, android-loadermanager, android-cursor

My Custom Adapter that extends `SimpleCursorAdapter` for my `ListFragment` does not display the items in my database correctly. it does not display the text in the TextView, what else do I have to do to the cursor for it to show the correct text?

I thought I had to override the `bindView` but that had no effect

Setting the adapter:

```
public void populateList(){

        String[] fields = new String[] {BowlersDB.NAME};
        Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(BowlersDB.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[] {BowlersDB.ID,BowlersDB.NAME},null,null,BowlersDB.NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");

mAdapter = new CheckAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.check_listview,c,fields,new int[] {R.id.nameCheckTV});


        setListAdapter(mAdapter);   

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0,null,this);
    }
```

Adapter:

```
public class CheckAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{

    Context context;
    Cursor c;

    public CheckAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
        this.context = context;
        this.c = c;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view,Context context,Cursor cursor){
        String st = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BowlersDB.NAME));

        TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.nameCheckTV);
        tv.setText(st);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent){
        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflator = getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.check_listview,null);
        }

        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);   
            cb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    CheckBox check = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
                    int pos = position;
                    if(check.isChecked()){
                        mCheckedItems.add(position);
                    }else if(!check.isChecked()){
                        for(int i=0;i< mCheckedItems.size();i++){
                            if(mCheckedItems.get(i) == position){
                                mCheckedItems.remove(i);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            });
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: the constructor you are currently using is deprecated and may result in poor responsiveness. use the second one described here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html

Comment: i'm also unsure why you are directly querying for a `Cursor` in your `onCreate()` method. if you are implementing the `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>` then this should be done for you by the system (assuming you have implemented your `onCreateLoader()` method correctly).

Comment: In your bindView method, try logging the st String.

Comment: it seems bindView is never getting called

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I got it. Check out the implementation for [`CursorAdapter.getView()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/android/widget/CursorAdapter.java#CursorAdapter.getView%28int%2Candroid.view.View%2Candroid.view.ViewGroup%29). Notice how `bindView()` and `newView()` are called within `getView()`. It looks like by overriding `getView()` you are ensuring that your `CursorAdapter` never calls `bindView()`. Either put everything ONLY in `getView()` or ONLY in `newView()` and `bindView()`, but not both.

---

**EDIT I:**

Four things:

1. I've read up on `CursorAdapter`s and it looks like you want to override `bindView()` instead of `getView()`. It looks like `getView()` is called twice for each row that's to be displayed and this is somehow preventing the cursor from being updated and thus always points to the first row. I think this is why your `ListView` only displays the first row. Further, the default `CursorAdapter` implementation for a ListView will recycle views for you, so overriding `getView()` really isn't necessary (check out this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3535129/844882) for more info).
2. When creating your `mAdapter`, you should pass a null `Cursor` into the constructor. The `Cursor` will be delivered in `onLoadFinished` (when the `Loader` has finished the query) and will be bound to the adapter with `swapCursor(cursor)`.
3. Your `onCreateLoader()` method will create (or start) the `Loader` that will perform the initial query. Make sure it looks something like this,

   ```
   @Override
   public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
       String[] projection = { BowlersDB.ID, BowlersDB.NAME };

       CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
               BowlersDB.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
       return cursorLoader;
   }
   ```
4. Make sure you make use of the correct `SimpleCursorAdapter` constructor... the one you are currently using is deprecated! (pass `0`as a flag... the `CursorLoader` will register a content observer for you so you don't need to pass in anything special).

---

**EDIT II:**

To clarify, the `bindView()` method is where you populate your row's widgets with the data from the `Cursor`'s current position. You are handed the `Cursor` pre-positioned at the proper row. You need to pull data out of the `Cursor` and pour it into your desired widgets. In other words, you'll need to query for the row's id (instead of using the "position" argument in `getView()`). Try setting the `onClickListener` in `bindView()` with something like:

```
final int rowId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));

CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);   
cb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = rowId;
        /* you now know this row's position. do what you need to do. */
    }
});
```

Comment: I originally did that but when trying to use the cursor I would get NullPointerException because there was no cursor fed in which is why I had that query in the create method. when doing that the listview would only display the first row in the cursor so it seems I would then have to iterate through the cursor but how i guess is the question. if it was an array I would just use the position variable but I cant use that with a cursor

Comment: the reason I was using `getView()` is because when the checkbox is clicked the `onclicklistener` in the `getView` knows the position checked so using the `bindView` would then again bring me back to the problem of getting the id of the list item checked. I was going off of this example hor help http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listadvanced_interactive