# View disappearing when inflated

Tags: android, user-interface, android-inflate

I have a custom ListActivity in which i have a custom ListAdapter that inflates a layout for each item in the list. In eclipse, in the visual editor the layout looks like this
[image: Eclipse's layout]

This is made by the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/largeFrame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@color/mainBack"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <View
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/newtimeslot_class"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/newtimeslot_class"
            android:layout_below="@+id/newtimeslot_class"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/newtimeslot_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/newtimeslot_class"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#646464" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/newtimeslot_location"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#646464" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/newtimeslot_comment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/newtimeslot_location"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#646464" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Unfortunately though, when i run this on an android device, the line to the left completely disappears. It instead looks like

[image]

I have just done the usual in terms on inflating it, and i only ever access the TextView objects. So i'm just wondering what could possibly be going on and if someone could help me out of this mess?

Cheers

Edit: The inflation code

```
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    final View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.timeslotlayout_new, parent, false);

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Please post the code of inflation

Comment: Just done so, the override is of a the superclass CursorAdapter

Comment: Please post some more code. I think you are using the overriden method for inflating the layout which is `public View getView(int p_position, View p_convertView, ViewGroup p_parent)`.

Comment: What of would be helpful? This is the only interaction that ever happens with this

And this is why i've used newView http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535074/getview-vs-bindview-in-a-custom-cursoradapter

Comment: `android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="false"` should be `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`

Comment: Ah sorry about that, i was just trying that out. It wasn't usually in the code. I'll fix it in the question. It doesn't fix it sadly

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the reference **@android:color/darker_gray** to be the problem.

It might be that on some devices, this value does not exist ?!? (it may be under another name for instance)

Try setting the background attribute to a COLOR *value* (instead of an android color *reference*) like this **#00000** which represents **black** (or choose another custom color like this **#A9A9A9** for **DarkGray** ) :

```
android:background="#A9A9A9"
```

/OR/

Create an XML file for most basic colors like done [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7323234/1542438), in this manner you are sure that the colors will not change among devices, and most of all, that they will exist on all devices for your application.

So if you do so (see the link), you can create a color like this (the name of the XML file does not matter at all) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <color name="Black">#000000</color>
   <color name="DarkGray">#A9A9A9</color>
</resources>
```

And reference it in the following way :

```
android:background="@color/DarkGray"
```

---

*Note :
No matter if this solved your issue or not, I strongly advise you to follow this manner to be on the safe side.*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're missing to set this:

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
```

to this:

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
```

And, by the way, `android:orientation="vertical"` doesn't apply to a relative layout. It applies only to `LinearLayout`.

And to the `newtimeslot_time` `TextView` change the

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
```

to

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView1"
```

Hope it helps!

Cheers!

Comment: Fixed up all those issues, nothing changed in the slightest. This is very strange. Cheers for trying!