# how do I add alternate background code to an adapter without getview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I am trying to add my alternate background code in java to an adapter that is not using getview method. Can any one please guide me how I can override/create the getview method? Here's the code i need to add in getview :

```
if (position % 2 == 0){
            addView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.oddcellcolor);
        } else {
            addView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.evencellcolor);
        }
```

Any help appreciated! Thanks! Justin

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean "an adapter that is not using getview method".  The Adapter doesn't use getView - it provides getView, and that is used by the AdapterView that owns the Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You could just look in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html) for the adaper and find the getView method in there....

but for the lazy this is what you have to override

```
getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

Comment: I added the code mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535074/getview-vs-bindview-in-a-custom-cursoradapter , but everytime i plugged in my code above , it caused crash in the application whenever i went to that page, any clue how to fix the issue?

Comment: @JusticeBauer well you are going to have to give more information like code and the error

Comment: just to reiterate, in the stackoverflow link i sent, one with 4 votes( the answer) , can i use that? as soon as i plug my code if(position%2 ==0) etc.. into it, it doesnt recognize it and crashes, is it possible to create an all new getview method and ass this code right there? or should i follow some other approach?

Comment: you "create a new getview" by overriding the getView so like I said post more code of what you did and post the error